# Find a manifold with boundary of a geodesic ball being a torus

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry

I would like to find the answers to the following questions:

> **a.** Find a complete $3$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ and a point $p\in M$, such that the boundary of the open geodesic ball $B(p,1)$ is a smooth $2$-dimensional manifold and is diffeomorphic to the torus $T^2$.
>
> **b.** Is there a complete $3$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ and a point $p\in M$, such that the boundary of the open geodesic ball $B(p,r)$ for some $r>0$ is a smooth $2$-dimensional manifold and is *isometric* to the flat torus $T^2$? (The flat torus is defined as the direct product of two copies of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$)

Thanks for any help to the questions in advance.

Comment: These look like potential homework problems in a 3-manifold theory course. Have you studied any knot theory?

Comment: @RyanBudney These are some homework problems in our Riemannian geometry course. I know little about knot theory...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because MO is not for helping out with homework or assigned exercises